# Layout load recyclerView slowly

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, load, android-inflate

Activity loading layout file, if the layout contains RecyclerView, through startActivity into when the UI is particularly slow, there are about 0.5-2 seconds waiting time, but if you remove RecyclerView when enters the normal!Activity didn't write other code, just loaded a blank layout, test is so many times.What is the problem?Is there a solution?